# vim search for lines that do not start with a particular string

Tags: regex, search, vim

I have a file with hundreds of thousands of lines that start with a date, e.g.

```
2021-02-22...
```

but some odd lines do not start that way. My intention is to write a macro to find them and join them with the line above.

How can I search for such lines from within vim?

E.g., if I wanted to find the next matching line in vim, I would type

```
/^2021
```

and it would take me to the next line that starts with "2021"

I want to do this, but search for the next **non-matching** line.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://superuser.com/questions/383939/how-to-do-a-vim-search-inverse-search-for-all-lines-with-out-text

Comment: I don't want to generate a list of all non-matching lines, I want to move to the next non-matching line.  Like what "/" does, but for non-matching patterns

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1456061/6064933

Answer (score 10):

> My intention is to write a macro to find them and join them with the line above.

That kind of operation is usually done with `:help :global`:

```
:g!/<pattern>/<command>
```

which executes `<command>` on each line *not* matching `<pattern>`.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
:g!/^2021/-j
```

where…

- `^2021` is your pattern,
- `-j` first sets the address to the line above and then joins it with the following one.

You may find this alternative more intuitive:

```
:g!/^2021/norm! kJ
```

which essentially uses the normal mode equivalent of `:-j`.

If you have several years in that file, consider a simple alternation:

```
:g!/^\(2021\|2020\|2019\)/-j
```

or a more generic pattern:

```
:g!/^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d/-j
```

You don't have to try to be smart, here, with quantifiers and negative look-behinds and stuff.

Reference:

```
:help :global
:help :range
:help :join
:help :normal
:help k
:help J
:help /^
:help \d
:help /\|
:help /\(
```

Comment: Would `:join` with a negative range also work? e.g `:g!/^2021/.-1join`, `:v/^2021/-j`

Comment: @PeterRincker `:g!/^2021/-j` or `:v/^2021/-j` would work, yes. Do you think I should add it to my answer or do you want to post your own?

Comment: I think adding it to your comment would be best. It is really just using the `:join` command which is very similar to normal `j`.

Answer (score 5):

We can use look around regex in Vim to tackle this kind of question. If I understand you correctly, you want to search a line not starting with 2021, right?

The following search pattern works:

```
/\v^(2021)@!
```

A teardown of this search:

- `\v`: use magic search, which will simplify the vim regex, see also `:h \v`.
- `^`: matches start of a line
- `(2021)@!`: `@!` is negative look ahead, i.e., after start of line, the following patter shouldn't be 2021, the parentheses here means a regex group.

Answer (score 0):

This finds and selects a non-empty line that does not start with `2021`:

```
/^[^2]\([^0]\([^2]\([^1]\)\?\)\?\)\?.*
```

Explanation:

- `[^2]` - expect a char that is not `2`
- add other numbers as optional chars with nesting, using `\([^<d>]\)\?`, where `<d>` represents a digit

Comment: FYI, I also tried a negative lookbehind and lookahead, such as `/^\(\)\@!2021` but that did not work.